# How to refresh ScrollView/LinearLayout in Kotlin

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

i'm trying to solve my problem. When I made some basic weather app. When I open new activity I can add city to favourite list. The problem is when i push back button, I need to refresh scrollview, but i dont know how. I tried onBackPressed but it doesn't work.

Here is a part of code

```
fun showWeather(searchedCity: String?) {
        var city: CityObject
        if (searchedCity.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "NEED TO WRITE CITY!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        // Need have threat cause internet
        thread = Thread {
            // getting data
            var jsonData = jsonParser.getJsonData("$searchedCity")
            if (!jsonData.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                //parsing data
                city = jsonParser.parseJsonData(jsonData)!!
                // for start another activity
                startActivity(city)
            }
        }
        thread.start()
        textInputEditText.text?.clear()
    }

    //showing weather
    fun startActivity(city: CityObject) {
        runOnUiThread {
            val intent = Intent(this, WeatherActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("CITY_OBJECT", city)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    // making favourite cities buttons
    fun getFavouriteCities() {
        linInScroll.removeAllViews()
        linInScroll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        for (cityName in DB.getData()) {
            val button = Button(this)
            button.setText("$cityName")
            button.setTextSize(1, 20F)
            button.setOnClickListener {
                showWeather("$cityName")
            }
            linInScroll.addView(button)
        }
    }
```

List of favourite cities

[image]

Thanks for help

Comment: Hi, can you try calling getFavouriteCities()  in onResume() method.

Comment: Amazing ! It works! Thank u so much !

Comment: If ``onResume`` is good for you that's cool (bear in mind it's called every time the app comes into view, when the display is rotated etc) but the proper way to handle the back button is by adding an ``OnBackPressedCallback``: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time your activity comes to foreground `onResume` method is called.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    getFavouriteCities()
}
```

There are other lifecycle events that you might want to take a look.

Do check out [android activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#activity-lifecycle) for better understanding.

> [image: Android lifecycle]